# NSAttributedString Writing Direction

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, right-to-left

I am trying to change the write direction in an NSAttributedString. However, I have a really hard time figuring out how to do it.

```
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"ArialRoundedMTBold", 16, NULL);

NSDictionary *attrDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)fontRef,(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, nil];
CFRelease(fontRef);

NSAttributedString *attString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.stringMap attributes:attrDictionary];

self.attString = attString;
```

This is the code in which I initialise my NSAttributedString and I have read about the constant **kCTWritingDirectionRightToLeft** and I feel like I have to put it in somewhere but I can figure out where and how.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Look at `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` there: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ye I have looked at it earlier and it's all good but how do I utilize it? I always find apples documentation lacking examples.

Comment: My guess (didn't try): Key: `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName`, Object: `@(1)`.

Comment: Can't get it to work :S looking in the code it says "Value must be a CFArray of CFNumberRefs" - would this correspond to a CFArray: @(kCTWritingDirectionLeftToRight | kCTTextWritingDirectionEmbedding) ?

Comment: What did you wrote? I would have wrote: NSDictionary *attrDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)fontRef,(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, @(1), NSWritingDirectionAttributeName];

Comment: Ye I tried that as well. It did not complain, however, it did not change anything as well. I have also tried with: NSDictionary *attrDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)fontRef,(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, @(kCTWritingDirectionRightToLeft | kCTWritingDirectionOverride),kCTWritingDirectionAttributeName,nil]; - no success.

Answer (score 8):

I read more carefully the doc.

I'll use `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` since I'm more confortable with them than using all the `bridge` stuff, and also shorthand syntax.

So `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` waits for a `NSArray` of NSNumbers. That was the issue.
One of theses numbers must be a *NSWritingDirection* (*LeftToRight* or *RightToLeft*), and the other a *NSTextWritingDirection* (*Embedding* or *Override*).

So, the combinations possibles are (and I think you're looking for the forth one):

```
NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                 NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft | NSTextWritingDirectionOverride)]};

NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                 NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSWritingDirectionLeftToRight | NSTextWritingDirectionEmbedding)]};

NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                 NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSWritingDirectionLeftToRight | NSTextWritingDirectionOverride)]};

NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                 NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft | NSTextWritingDirectionOverride)]};
```

[Source: Documentation of `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nswritingdirectionattributename)