# Undetected crash when creating an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsattributedstring

I have a crash when adding an attributed string method which returns the attributed string, the crash is:

```
-[_SwiftValue count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is my code:

```
func attributedTextForTitle(name: String, indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString {

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.right

    let nameIndexPath = String(indexPath.row + 1)
    let attStringText = "\(nameIndexPath). \(name)"

    let multipleAttributes: [String : Any] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Alef-Bold", size: 16.0)!,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
        NSWritingDirectionAttributeName : NSWritingDirection.rightToLeft
    ]

    return NSAttributedString(string: attStringText, attributes: multipleAttributes)
}
```

Can someone identify what seems to be the problem? Also, how can I find out the problem myself next time in this case without asking a question ;)

Comment: Which line crashes?

Comment: did you make sure that's exactly how you spell the font name?

Comment: The line crashing seems to not be here provided...

Comment: `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` value is wrong. According to the doc it needs at least 2 values (you can check my answer in Obj-C (with explanations on the possibilities): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158772/nsattributedstring-writing-direction and in an Array, that's you have a "-[_SwiftValue count]" error, it's using `count` of array on a `SwiftValue`. For the Swift way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785746/how-to-use-nswritingdirectionattributename-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in a playground and it was interesting to see where the error came from. It turned out that the line where you create the 'multipleAttributes' was where the issue was. Specifically:

```
UIFont(name: "Alef-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

This was returning nil and ultimately making the function throw that weird error.

I'd pull that line out and then do some error checking before just throwing it into the multipleAttributes array.